# Symfony ChoiceType grouped by 2 database table

Tags: forms, symfony, select

i have two table in database with field 
TIPOLOGY{id,name}
EXAME{id,name,id_tipology}

I need to create a select list grouped by TIPOLOGY

```
 $builder->add('select_exame', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'label' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'choices' => array(
           'typology_name'=>array(
                                   'exame_name_1'=>'id_exame_1'
                                   'exame_name_2'=>'id_exame_2'
                                   )
           'typology_name_2'=>array(
                                   'exame_name_3'=>'id_exame_3'
                                   )
    ),
   )
```

but i don't find how to do this . can you help me?

Comment: This needs to be an entity type rather than choice. You then need to write the database query needed within the entity repository and call it from within the form. I don't have time right now to give an example but a search of Google for symfony entity form type will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes , they are two entity

Entity Esame

```
class Esame
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nome", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nome;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame
 *
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Nome_esame")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_tipologia_esame", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idTipologiaEsame;
```

entity tipologia

```
class tipologiaesame
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tipo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $tipo;
```

and i try to do this

```
 $builder->add('select_exame', EntityType::class, array(
    'label' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Esame',
    'choice_label' => 'nome',
    'group_by' => 'idTipologiaEsame.nome',
   )
```

now it work